# jQuery, selecting just number from id like "article-23"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All right, I have a div tag which got a `class="blog-post"` and id like `id="article-23"` (where "23" could be any number, as it is id of blog post in a database). I need to somehow get just a number from that id and than apply some rules to that div tag. So say:

```
if number from id % 2 == 0 {
  set text colour black to associated div tag with class of blog-post
} else {
  set text colour white to associated div tag with class of blog-post
}
```

Thats just a "pseudo" code to show logic that I wan't to apply dependent if number from id is even or odd, but the question remains same, how do I just get number from id like "article-23" ?

Comment: @meagar That's worth expanding to an answer with an example.

Comment: @meagar could you provide a source or example please

Comment: @Ilya Knaup: `<div ... data-id="23" ...>`. `$div.data('id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.blog-post[id^="article-"]').each(function () {
    if (parseInt(this.id.replace('article-', '')) % 2 === 0) {
        $('#' + this.id).css('color', 'black');
    } else {
        $('#' + this.id).css('color', 'white');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/VPH55/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As simple as

```
var number = "article-23".match(/\d+/)[0];
```

But you have to be sure that any digit exists in the string, otherwise you'd get a error.

Comment: I don't quiet understand how this works, also "article-23" is not static, it will change all the time to things like "article-2".. "article-987" etc.. how would I get these, in some sense, different values in? can I somehow use class of the div to get it's id?

Comment: @Ilya Knaup: your question was - how to extract a number from a string, not how to get the id value from the DOM node. Do you realize they are *different* tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually apply rules via function, which makes this the cleanest solution (in my opinion):

```
$(".blog-post").css('color', function () {
    return +this.id.replace('article-', '') % 2 ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Jrc5u/

Comment: Doesn't `%` cast operands implicitly?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know, but the `+` casts to number

Comment: my comment implicitly asserted that :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, HTML5 supports these things called "data attributes", which are specifically meant for attaching data to your DOM without abusing things like the "class" or "id" attributes. jQuery provides a handy `.data` method for reading these attributes in a more obvious way.

You can add your own numeric ID attribute using something like "data-id":

```
<div class="blog-post" data-id="23" />
```

```
$("#blog-post").each(function () {
  console.log($(this).data("id")); // Look up the data-id attribute
});
```

Comment: Will this data id only work in html browsers? I'm using something similar for my icon font, and for some strange reason it still works in browsers like ie8, I never realised it was an html5 element, strange.

Comment: "Html browsers"? As opposed to...?

Comment: Sorry, must be tired, I meant html5 browsers, also I tried your solution out, but it doesn't seem to work (I added data attributes in markup as well): $(".blog-post").each(function () {
   var articleId = $(this).data("id"));
  if (articleId % 2 == 0) {
   $(this).css({ marginTop: 10 }).animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 550);
  } else {
   $(this).css({ marginTop: 10 }).animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 650);
  }
 });

Comment: You're going to have to convert the value to an integer. `articleId = parseInt(articleId, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the number after the hyphen of the id tag of your .blog-post class.

```
var article = $(".blog-post").attr('id'); //get the id
var article = article.split("-");  // split it on hyphens
return article = article[article.length-1];  // return the last element
```